# Cannot get the child element of md-dialog using querySelector/getElementById

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

How can I get the child element of `<md-dialog>` using the element's id?

Here are the following workaround I did:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('input-file-upload')); // returns null
console.log(document.querySelector('#input-file-upload')); // returns null
```

But it returns `null` please see this [demo](https://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/LyPeRz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the modal is open. If you put your code inside a `$timeout` it works.

```
$timeout(function(){
    // HERE is the Problem i cannot get input file element by queryselector/getElementById
    console.log(document.getElementById('input-file-upload')) // returns null
    console.log(document.querySelector('#input-file-upload')) // returns null
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `onComplete` property of $mdDialog.